# Default selected radio button disappears after page reload in Next/React.js

Tags: reactjs, radio-button, next.js13, app-router

The default selection works fine when navigating to the page via a router link (imported as Link from 'next/link'). However, when the page is reloaded, the default selected option momentarily appears and then disappears.

Next.js 13.4.8
React.js 18.2.0

Using new Next.js App Router.

ShopItem component:

```
"use client"

import Image from 'next/image';
import React, { useState } from 'react';


function ShopItem({ item }) {
    // Find the default size object
    const defaultSize = item.sizes.find(sizeObj => sizeObj.default) || item.sizes[1]; // Fallback to first size if no default found

    // Initialize state to store the currently selected size and price
    const [selectedSize, setSelectedSize] = useState(defaultSize.size);
    const [selectedPrice, setSelectedPrice] = useState(defaultSize.price);
    
    const handleSizeChange = (size, price) => {
        setSelectedSize(size);
        setSelectedPrice(price);
    };

    return (
        <div className="shop__item">
            <Image
                className="shop__item__img"
                src={item.image}
                width={500}
                height={500}
                alt={item.name}
            />

            <div className="shop__item__content-wrapper">
                <h2 className="shop__item__content shop__item__content__name">
                    {item.name}
                </h2>

                <div className="shop__item__content__weight-wrapper">
                    {item.sizes.map((sizeObj, index) => (
                        <React.Fragment key={index}>
                            <input 
                                type="radio" 
                                id={`weight-${sizeObj.size}-${item.id}`} 
                                name={`weight-${item.id}`} 
                                value={sizeObj.size} 
                                onChange={() => handleSizeChange(sizeObj.size, sizeObj.price)}
                                checked={sizeObj.size === selectedSize}
                                className="visually-hidden"
                            />
                            <label htmlFor={`weight-${sizeObj.size}-${item.id}`} className="button shop__item__content shop__item__content__weight">{sizeObj.size}</label>
                        </React.Fragment>
                    ))}
                </div>

                <div className="shop__item__content shop__item__content__price">
                    {selectedPrice} zł
                </div>
                <button className="button-big shop__item__content shop__item__content__add-to-cart">
                    Add to Cart
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default ShopItem;
```

using this component in page.js:

```
import ShopItem from "./shop-item.js";

export default function Shop() {
    const items = [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: "Miód rzepakowy",
          image: "/img/home/jak-rozpoznac.jpg",
          sizes: [
            { size: "250 G", price: 59.9 },
            { size: "450 G", price: 79.9, default: true },
            { size: "1 KG", price: 99.9 }
          ],
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: "Miód rzepakowy\nz nutką gryki",
          image: "/img/logo.png",
          sizes: [
            { size: "250 G", price: 59.9 },
            { size: "450 G", price: 79.9 },
            { size: "1 KG", price: 99.9, default: true }
          ],
        },
    ];
    
  return (
    <main className="page-wrapper main shop">
        <div className="shop__1">
        {items.map((item) => (
            <ShopItem key={item.id} item={item} />
        ))}
        </div>
    </main>
  );
}
```

Please help ^_^

Tried lazy initialization of the state
`const [selectedPrice, setSelectedPrice] = useState(() => defaultSize.price);`
instead of
`const [selectedPrice, setSelectedPrice] = useState(defaultSize.price);`

also tried passing default value as a prop, thought maybe it is because of server-side rendering of the parent component.

Answer (score 0):

It's Next.js bug. There are some temporary solutions here https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/49499

As you use controlled inputs you can remove 'name' property for now and it will work